# GradientTape not computing gradient

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, gradienttape

I understand that so long as i am defining a computation in `tf.GradientTape()` context, the gradient tape would compute the gradient w.r.t all the variables that the output of the computation depends on. However, i think i am not quite grasping the subtelties of the gradient as the following code does not execute as i expect it to:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable(2.)
loss_ = x**2-2*x+1
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g:
    loss = loss_*1
print(g.gradient(loss,x))
output: None
```

Why is the gradient wrt x not computed?

I am able to compute only the gradients that are wrt to the variables that are getting explicitly used within the context. for example the following code does not compute gradients as well:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
x = tf.Variable(2.)
t1 = x**2
t2 = -2*x
t3 = 1.
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g:
    loss = t1+t2+t3
print(g.gradient(loss,x))
```

Comment: You need the computation of `loss_` inside the tape context.

Comment: but im computing `loss` inside the context and i am computing gradinet of `loss` not `loss_` .. ?? what exactly is the way to do it exactly?

Comment: The entire computation from start to finish needs to be inside the scope. Things that happen outside the scope are not traced. As your code is right now, the tape knows that `loss` comes from `loss_` but it has no idea that `loss_` comes from `x`, and so no gradients can be computed.

Answer (score 1):

The `GradientTape` object `g` goes out of scope after the `with` statement ends.

In other words, try printing the gradient inside the `with` statement.

Here's what works for me:

```
def get_gradients(inputs, target, model):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        prediction = model(inputs)
        loss = loss_object(target, prediction)
        gradient = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)

    return gradient
```

Comment: no it does not. In fact i get the warning: WARNING:tensorflow:Calling GradientTape.gradient on a persistent tape inside its context is significantly less efficient than calling it outside the context (it causes the gradient ops to be recorded on the tape, leading to increased CPU and memory usage). Only call GradientTape.gradient inside the context if you actually want to trace the gradient in order to compute higher order derivatives.
None

Comment: OK so my second guess it that maybe your loss is defined incorrectly. Maybe try to define it using Keras.backend operations (as well as the variable itself)

Comment: Also check my example: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18NMvNdoAn1Ip9GmFt6A_Qvqd3jY1honP?usp=sharing

Comment: @asaf92 Your example is nice, but it seems that 1) you need a `modelGradients.set_weights(modelFit.get_weights())` in order to initialize the models with the same weights 2) for larger inputs and outputs you need the inputs and outputs to be two-dimensional (otherwise updates don't seem to match) 3) we must ensure that  `fit` and `train` operate on exactly the same batches.